# Converting Date and Gender to String using Apache-poi

Tags: java, database, date, numbers, apache-poi

```
 Date displayVistDate = viewInvoice.getBillingDate();        //Variables in database
 Gender displayGender = viewInvoice.getBillingGender();
 LoginUser displayCustomerID = viewInvoice.getCustomerID(); //This one has both number and character.

 tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("BOXY1285");            // how do i get it here.
```

How can I set **Date** and **Gender** that is in the database?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see our help section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . We need to see the code for getBillingGender() and getBillingDate(), please.

Comment: XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();            
        tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText(AGE_GENDER);
        tableRowTwo.getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0).getRuns().get(0).setBold(true);
        tableRowTwo.getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0).setSpacingBefore(8*10);
        tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText(displayCustomerAge); // this one is from DataBase

Comment: tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText(VISIT_DATE);
        tableRowTwo.getCell(2).getParagraphs().get(0).getRuns().get(0).setBold(true);
        tableRowTwo.getCell(2).getParagraphs().get(0).setSpacingBefore(7*10);
        tableRowTwo.getCell(3).setText(formatedDate);  // this one is from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write `Date` and `Gender` in `Cell` you need to convert them to `String`. E.g. for `Gender` you can probably use either `.toString()` or `.name()`: `.setText(displayGender.toString())`.

Comment: Thank you very much it's working.. :)